# Finding undiscounted prices with vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to make invoice transactions with vuejs. everything works flawlessly. the only problem is E.g;
When the net total with 10% discount is written, I want the (Unit Price) gross to be written,
I couldn't do the math.

I want to checkout "1062" with "10%" discount. and if the discount input is 0, I want it to write the net total without discount

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    invoiceItems: [{
      name: "",
      quantity: 0,
      unit_price: 0,
      vat: 0, // KDV TUTARI
      vat_rate: 18, // KDV YÜZDESİ
      invoice_discount: 0, // FATURA İNDİRİMİ
      net_total: 0,
      net_total_raw: 0,
      description: '',

      discount: 0, // İNDİRİM TUTARI
      discount_value: 0, // İNDİRİM TUTARI
      discount_rate: 0, // İNDİRİM YÜZDESİ
      discount_type: 'percentage', // İNDİRİM YÜZDE VEYA PARA
      excise_duty: 0, // ÖTV TUTARI
      excise_duty_value: 0, // ÖTV TUTARI
      excise_duty_rate: 0, // ÖTV YÜZDESİ
      excise_duty_type: 'percentage', // ÖTV YÜZDE VEYA PARA

      communications_tax: 0, // ÖİV TUTARI
      communications_tax_rate: 0, // ÖİV YÜZDESİ
      showDesc: false,
      showDiscount: false,
      showOtv: false,
      showOiv: false,
    }, ],
  },
  methods: {
    addInvoice() {
      this.invoiceItems.push({
        name: "",
        quantity: 0,
        unit_price: 0,
        vat: 0, // KDV TUTARI
        vat_rate: 18, // KDV YÜZDESİ
        invoice_discount: 0, // FATURA İNDİRİMİ
        net_total: 0,
        net_total_raw: 0,
        description: '',

        discount: 0, // İNDİRİM TUTARI
        discount_value: 0, // İNDİRİM TUTARI
        discount_rate: 0, // İNDİRİM YÜZDESİ
        discount_type: 'percentage', // İNDİRİM YÜZDE VEYA PARA
        excise_duty: 0, // ÖTV TUTARI
        excise_duty_value: 0, // ÖTV TUTARI
        excise_duty_rate: 0, // ÖTV YÜZDESİ
        excise_duty_type: 'percentage', // ÖTV YÜZDE VEYA PARA

        communications_tax: 0, // ÖİV TUTARI
        communications_tax_rate: 0, // ÖİV YÜZDESİ
        showDesc: false,
        showDiscount: false,
        showOtv: false,
        showOiv: false,
      });
    },
    removeIncoiceItem(index) {
      this.invoiceItems.splice(index, 1);
    },
    fixMoney(money) {
      let _money = parseFloat(money.toFixed(2));

      _money = !isNaN(_money) ? _money : 0;

      return _money;
    },
    calculateUnitPrice(index, event) {

      let item = this.invoiceItems[index];
      let totalPrice = item.net_total,
        discount = item.discount,
        discountRate = item.discount_rate,
        discountValue = item.discount_value,
        discountType = item.discount_type,
        exciseDuty = item.excise_duty,
        exciseRate = item.excise_duty_rate,
        exciseValue = item.excise_duty_value,
        exciseType = item.excise_duty_type,
        communicationsTax = item.communications_tax,
        communicationsTaxRate = item.communications_tax_rate,
        newGross = item.unit_price;
      item.quantity = item.quantity === 0 ? 1 : item.quantity;



      let unitPriceTotal = item.net_total / (1 + item.vat_rate / 100),
        unitPrice = this.fixMoney(unitPriceTotal / item.quantity);


      if (discountValue > 0) {
        if (discountType === "percentage") {
        //discount = item.unit_price * item.quantity - (item.unit_price * item.quantity - (item.unit_price * (item.discount_value / 100)));
        //totalPrice = (item.unit_price * item.quantity - (item.unit_price * item.quantity * (item.discount_value / 100)));
        
          const brut = item.net_total / (1 + item.vat_rate / 100);
          const yeni = brut * item.quantity - (brut * item.quantity - (brut * (item.discount_value / 100)))
          console.log("indirim",yeni)
        
        } else {
          console.log("burasıs else")
          
        }
      }
      



      this.invoiceItems[index].quantity = item.quantity;
      this.invoiceItems[index].unit_price = unitPrice;
      //this.invoiceItems[index].net_total_raw = totalPrice;

    },
    calculateTotalPrice(index) {
      let item = this.invoiceItems[index],
        totalPrice = 0;
      item.quantity = item.quantity === 0 ? 1 : item.quantity;
      if (item.unit_price !== 0) {
        totalPrice = item.unit_price * item.quantity;
        totalPrice = totalPrice + (totalPrice * (item.vat_rate / 100));
      }
      this.invoiceItems[index].quantity = item.quantity;
      this.invoiceItems[index].net_total = this.fixMoney(totalPrice);
      this.invoiceItems[index].net_total_raw = totalPrice;
      this.CustomHelper(index);
    },

    CustomHelper(index) {
      const item = this.invoiceItems[index];
      let totalPrice = item.net_total,
        discount = item.discount,
        discountRate = item.discount_rate,
        discountValue = item.discount_value,
        discountType = item.discount_type,
        exciseDuty = item.excise_duty,
        exciseRate = item.excise_duty_rate,
        exciseValue = item.excise_duty_value,
        exciseType = item.excise_duty_type,
        communicationsTax = item.communications_tax,
        communicationsTaxRate = item.communications_tax_rate,
        newGross = item.unit_price;

      if (discountType === "percentage") {
        discount = item.unit_price * item.quantity - (item.unit_price * item.quantity - (item.unit_price * (item.discount_value / 100)));
        totalPrice = (item.unit_price * item.quantity - (item.unit_price * item.quantity * (item.discount_value / 100)));
        newGross = totalPrice;
      } else {
        discount = item.unit_price * item.quantity - (item.unit_price * item.quantity - item.discount_value);
        totalPrice = (item.unit_price - item.discount_value);
        newGross = totalPrice;
      }
      newGross = totalPrice;
      if (exciseType === "percentage") {
        exciseDuty = (totalPrice * (item.excise_duty_value / 100));
        totalPrice = (totalPrice + (totalPrice * (item.excise_duty_value / 100)));
        newGross = totalPrice;
      } else {
        exciseDuty = item.unit_price - (item.unit_price - item.excise_duty_value);
        totalPrice = (newGross + item.excise_duty_value);
        newGross = totalPrice;
      }


      communicationsTax = (totalPrice * (item.communications_tax_rate / 100));
      totalPrice = newGross + (newGross * (item.vat_rate / 100)) + (communicationsTax);
      newGross = totalPrice;

      this.invoiceItems[index].discount = this.fixMoney(discount);
      this.invoiceItems[index].excise_duty = this.fixMoney(exciseDuty);
      this.invoiceItems[index].communications_tax = this.fixMoney(communicationsTax);
      this.invoiceItems[index].net_total = this.fixMoney(newGross);
    }

  },
  computed: {
    aratoplam() {
      return this.invoiceItems.reduce(
        (acc, item) => acc + item.quantity * item.unit_price, 0);
    },
    satirindirimi() {
      return this.invoiceItems.reduce(
        (acc, item) => acc + item.discount, 0);
    },
    bruttoplam() {
      return this.invoiceItems.reduce(
        (acc, item) => acc + (item.quantity * item.unit_price) - item.discount, 0);
    },
    toplamotv() {
      return this.invoiceItems.reduce(
        (acc, item) => acc + item.excise_duty, 0);
    },

    toplamovi() {
      return this.invoiceItems.reduce(
        (acc, item) => acc + item.communications_tax, 0);
    },
    toplamkdv() {
      return this.invoiceItems.reduce(
        (acc, item) => acc + (item.unit_price * item.quantity - item.discount + item.excise_duty) * (item.vat_rate / 100), 0);
    },
    geneltoplam() {
      return this.invoiceItems.reduce(
        (acc, item) => acc + (item.net_total), 0);
    }

  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <section class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th style="width:10%">Name</th>
            <th style="width:10%">Quantity</th>
            <th style="width:10%">Unit Price</th>
            <th style="width:5%">Vat Rate</th>
            <th style="width:10%">Net Total</th>
            <th style="width:25%">Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody v-for="(item, index) in invoiceItems" :key="index" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="text" v-model="item.name">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="number" v-model.number="item.quantity" @input="calculateTotalPrice(index)">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="number" v-model.number="item.unit_price" @input="calculateTotalPrice(index)">
            </td>

            <td>
              <select v-model="item.vat_rate" @change="calculateTotalPrice(index)">
                <option value="18">%18</option>
                <option value="8">%8</option>
                <option value="1">%1</option>
                <option value="0">%0</option>
              </select>
            </td>

            <td>
              <input type="number" v-model.number="item.net_total" @input="calculateUnitPrice(index)">
            </td>

            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" v-if="!item.showDesc" @click="item.showDesc = !item.showDesc">Description
              </button>
              <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-xs" v-if="!item.showDiscount" @click="item.showDiscount = !item.showDiscount">İNDİRİM
              </button>
              <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-xs" v-if="!item.showOtv" @click="item.showOtv = !item.showOtv">ÖTV
              </button>
              <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-xs" v-if="!item.showOiv" @click="item.showOiv = !item.showOiv">ÖİV
              </button>
              <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" @click="removeIncoiceItem(index)">X</button>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <th>
              <div v-if="item.showDesc">
                <input type="text" placeholder="description" v-model="item.description">
              </div>
            </th>
            <th>
              <div v-if="item.showDiscount">
                <input type="number" placeholder="discount_value" v-model.number="item.discount_value" @input="CustomHelper(index)">
                <select v-model="item.discount_type" @change="CustomHelper(index)">
                  <option value="amount">USD</option>
                  <option value="percentage">%</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th>
              <div v-if="item.showOtv">
                <input type="number" placeholder="excise_duty_value" v-model.number="item.excise_duty_value" @input="CustomHelper(index)">
                <select v-model="item.excise_duty_type" @change="CustomHelper(index)">
                  <option value="amount">USD</option>
                  <option value="percentage">%</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th>
              <div v-if="item.showOiv">
                <input type="number" placeholder="communications_tax_rate" v-model.number="item.communications_tax_rate" @input="CustomHelper(index)">
              </div>
            </th>
            <th></th>
            <th>
            </th>
          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>

      <hr>

      
      <div style="margin-top:10px">
        <button class="btn btn-warning" @click="addInvoice()"> Add Item</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cross-multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication)

```
if(this.discount > 0){
  this.unit_price -= (this.unit_price / 100) * this.discount
}
```